# Searching a file with two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file, bufferedreader

I have a file I need to be able to search a text file for students by ID number, and retrieve their scores by doing so. The text file is set up like this (with the long number being the Student id and the second being the scores):

```
66440   63
50940   6
71394   18
84789   77
41527   60
86258   30
51632   59
```

and so on. so far this is the code I have. It's not finished yet, and i need it to search for the first array (Students) and retrieve the second array (scores):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("scores.txt")))
            { 
            String sCurrentLine;
            String first = "Student ID: ";
            String second = "Score: ";
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {


                String[] information = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                String StudentID = information[0];
                String Score = information[1];
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter a user ID: ");
                String userID = input.nextLine();
                if (StudentID = userID){
                    System.out.println(Score);  
                }
    }}
}}
```

Comment: Read line by line and split by any number of white spaces and/or tabs. Parse them as `Integer`s if necessary. Store them in a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` (where the first is the `StudentID` and the other the `Score` or an `ArrayList<Student>`. Also note, variables are generally written with lowerCamelCase in Java. Please also remember to close the reader, and do not throw exceptions to the JVM. You can (should) close the reader in the `finally {}` clause.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader implements AutoCloseable and since 1.7 can by automatically close as a resource for try.
Im agree with Emz that firstly You should load whole files to memory and after that searching. You can declare hashMap with signature `Map<String,List<String>>` which as a key will have a student ID and as a values all scores. Retrieving scores for specific studdentId will be fast just `map.get(studentId).` In loop You can read inputs which try to retrive score from files or You can encode some specific character as a stop key for  main function.